# Unexpectedly or Unanticipatedly

Tags: differences, adverbs

Is there any difference in usage between the adverb 'unexpectedly' and 'unanticipatedly'

For Example :

We met each other **unexpectedly**/unanticipatedly

She approached me **unanticipatedly**/unexpectedly.

Can both words be used to mean the same thing something which is unforeseen?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127782/discussion-on-question-by-josh-unexpectedly-or-unanticipatedly).

Comment: Please provide the definitions you are working from, so that we can all be working from the same assumptions.

Comment: What do you mean by "usage"? Are you trying to ask whether there's any *semantic* difference between the two, or whether there's any difference in how the two are used *syntactically*, or are you seeking information on any difference in usage over *time* or in different *countries* (or in different *regions* or *dialects* or *social registers* within a particular country – and if so, *which country*)?

Answer (score 1):

*Unanticipatedly* is not a common word, but you could build up to it in a paragraph and use it effectively. For example:

She had studied her guests well, and knew what to expect…

Anticipated temper tantrum from Sarah’s three-year old daughter… Anticipatedly grabbing for the punch bowl anticipatedly placed a little further away this year.

Unanticipatedly standing on a box of Pellegrino bottles that the caterer had helpfully left under the table…

And so on.

A big advantage of English is the writer need not be bound by either the dictionary or the grammar handbook.

Playing with the expectations of the reader is like syncopation in music. It makes for livelier and more interesting prose.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncopation

Comment: A big advantage of English over what, FORTRAN? :)

Comment: Over pedants, mostly 